# Using FieldInfo.SetValue with a DynamicObject as argument 2

Tags: c#-4.0, dynamic

I ran into a problem today when trying to set a field using `FieldInfo.SetValue()` passing a `DynamicObject` as the second argument. In my case, the field is a `Guid` and the `DynamicObject` *should* be able to convert itself to a one (using `TryConvert`) but it fails with an `ArgumentException`.

Some code that shows the problem:

```
// Simple impl of a DynamicObject to prove point
public class MyDynamicObj : DynamicObject
{
    public override bool TryConvert(ConvertBinder binder, out object result)
    {
        result = null;
        // Support converting this to a Guid
        if (binder.Type == typeof(Guid))
        {
            result = Guid.NewGuid();
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
}

public class Test
{
    public Guid MyField;
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        dynamic myObj = new MyDynamicObj();

        // This conversion works just fine
        Guid guid = myObj;

        var test = new Test();
        var testField = typeof(Test).GetField("MyField");

        // This, however, fails with:
        // System.ArgumentException
        //   Object of type 'ConsoleApplication1.MyDynamicObj' cannot be converted to type 'System.Guid'.
        testField.SetValue(test, myObj);
    }
}
```

I'm not very familiar with the whole dynamicness of C# 4, but this felt to me like something that should work.. What am I doing wrong? Is there another way of doing this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, this shouldn't work - because the dynamic portion ends where your code ends. The compiler is calling a method with a signature of

```
void SetValue(Object obj, Object value)
```

That method call is dynamic, but it's *just* going to end up passing in a reference to the instance of `MyDynamicObj`. The call is resolved at execution time, but nothing in `SetValue` knows anything about the dynamic nature of the object whose reference you're passing in.

Basically you need to perform the dynamic part (the conversion in this case) in your code - the bit that involves the C# 4 compiler doing all its tricks. You've got to perform that conversion, and *then* you can call `SetField`.

To put it another way - it's a bit like calling `SetField` with a field of type `XName`, but passing in a string. Yes, there's a conversion from `string` to `XName`, but it's not `SetField`'s job to work that out. That's the compiler's job.

Now, you can get this to work by making the compiler do some of the work, but you still need to do some with reflection:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    dynamic myObj = new MyDynamicObj();

    var test = new Test();
    var testField = typeof(Test).GetField("MyField");

    var method = typeof(Program)
        .GetMethod("Convert", BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.NonPublic);
    method = method.MakeGenericMethod(testField.FieldType);

    object converted = method.Invoke(null, new object[] {myObj});
    testField.SetValue(test, converted);
}

static T Convert<T>(dynamic input)
{
    return input;
}
```

Comment: So, any way around it? Can I somehow trigger the conversion given that I only know the Type at runtime?

Answer (score 0):

You need an explicit cast to invoke the TryConvert:

```
testField.SetValue(test, (Guid)myObj);
```

Not sure if this is what you need though.  Maybe there's some way to reflectively say `((DynamicObject)myObj).TryConvert(/*reflected destination type here*/, result)`

Other attempts that failed, some of them require things like a certain interface be implemented, so they basically don't make use of TryConvert but maybe an alternative way to accomplish what you want:

```
  Type secondType = testField.FieldType;

  TypeConverter tc = TypeDescriptor.GetConverter(typeof(MyDynamicObj));
  object secondObject = tc.ConvertTo(myObj,typeof( Guid));
  //var secondObject = Convert.ChangeType(myObj, secondType);//Activator.CreateInstance(secondType);
  //secondObject =  myObj;
  testField.SetValue(test, secondObject);
```

Comment: Yep, in the "real" scenario I only know the type at runtime, so I'd need something like the TryConvert call you mentioned. Tried something like that though, but couldn't get it to run..